# Is there a way to make this url work for all pages?

Tags: url

I was doing web scraper but then I got blocked for too much commands and someone said I should retriev the json itself with this url and try play with it :https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=1490&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=price&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1
and I changed it to this :https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=0&count=100&search_descriptions=0&appid=730&norender=1 but when I try to do more than 100 it doesn't give me more outputs is there a way to fix this? Btw Iam new to programing and stuff, so I dont know much.

Comment: Well, if the maintainers of that URL blocks your access due to scraping, you need to ask the maintainers for details. I would assume that scraping violates their TOS

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.
These query parameters are most likely limited by Valve itself. Also, WebScraping / Crawling has the huge disadvantage that many or even most providers are actually blocking requests after a determined amount of requests / after a distinct use pattern whatsoever.

The only way to counteract this is to use an official API. By now, there's no such thing though.